# What does the () at the end of dynamic array allocate mean?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I have see some example like below in a different question which I have not seen before.

```
new int[m_size]();
               ^^
```

I have seen and used the version `new int[m_size]` all the time but not one with the `()` at the end.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two words : [Value Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new/620402#620402)

`new int[m_size]();` array elements would be zero-initialized by writing `()` because `()` implies value initialization.<sup>1</sup> (zero initialization for a primitive type)

<sub>1: An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized. ( $8.5/7 )</sub>

Comment: ah! So which type does it value initialise? Is it the pointer type of the whole expression or the individual members of the array?

Comment: @MeThinks : Check out `8.5/5` (Value Initialization). For a primitive type **Value initialization** => **Zero Initialization**. In this case the all the elements of the array would be initialized to `0`

Comment: ok. Got it in the standard "if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized". Thanks for the prompt response. First time I've come across it with respect to arrays.

Answer (score 2):

it means all the elements will be `zero initialized`,similar to `calloc(o,sizeof(int))` where with this calloc ,ur initializing a single integer on heap with `0`